# In Oracle what does parentheses do in a GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, group

I have seen GROUP BY clauses that look something like this:

```
GROUP BY id, permit, (date_sold)
```

I can't figure out what the () does and can not find it in any literature.

I have tried it with one of the tables we have an I don't any difference in the results.

Comment: Nothing at all. Just redundant.

Comment: But you can take a look at https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-grouping-sets/.

Answer (score 1):

> In Oracle what does parentheses do in a GROUP BY clause?

Nothing.

```sql
GROUP BY id, permit, (date_sold)
```

is exactly the same as:

```sql
GROUP BY id, permit, date_sold
```

If you wanted, you could write it as:

```sql
GROUP BY (((id))), ((((((permit)))))), (((((((((date_sold)))))))))
```

and it would function identically.

---

If you are grouping by arithmetic expressions then brackets can change the order in which operators are applied:

```sql
GROUP BY date_sold + num_days + num_weeks * 7
```

If you wrap the entire expression in brackets:

```sql
GROUP BY (date_sold + num_days + num_weeks * 7)
```

Then the meaning is identical to having no brackets.

But if you use brackets inside the expression:

```sql
GROUP BY date_sold + (num_days + num_weeks) * 7
```

Then the meaning is changed.

Comment: `(((((((((date_sold)))))))))` LOL